# Socket IO is working only on development mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, production

I have successfully developed the messaging component inside my application and I've tested it in development mode and it's working fine. When I deployed the code on Heroku to test it in production mode, it simply doesn't work. The messages are being received instantly only in development mode.

The server side code as below:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

// ...routes
// app.use(...routes)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const IO_PORT = process.env.IO_PORT || 8900;
const MODE = process.env.NODE_ENV;

app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${MODE} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.underline.bold,
  ),
);

const io = require("socket.io")(IO_PORT, {
  cors: {
    origin: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`, // dev: http://localhost:3000, prod: https://www.example.com
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // console.log(`user connected: ${socket.id}`);
}
```

The client side code as below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const MessageComponent = () => {
  const socket = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
      socket.current = io(`ws://${window.location.hostname}:8900`);

      // listening to events

  });
}
```

In production mode, the app shows the error below in the console:

GET https://www.example.com:8900/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Oftd3RH net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT         polling.js:311

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you allowed access to the 8900 port in production? Are you using reverse proxy like Nginx?

Comment: @Sanket I added 8900 in config vars. I don't know if I need to allow it and how? I don't use reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by binding the socket to the http server of the backend application that already exists.

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server); // <-

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// app.use(...routes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const MODE = process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

However, server is now listening to the incoming requests not app:

```
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running in ${MODE} mode on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

In the frontend, I simply used an empty argument list in the socket-client:

```
const socket = io();
```

But on mobile, I'm using react-native and I had to pass the full URL to the io() constructor:

```
const socket = io("https://www.example.com");
```

The socket is now listening on PORT 443 by default from Heroku.